# Quadratic probing: (f(k) + a*j + b*j^2) % M, How to choose a and b?

Tags: math, hash

If M is prime, how to choose a and b to minimize collisions?

Also in books it is written that to find the empty slot while quadratic probing in (f(k)+j^2) % M, the hash table has to be at least half empty? Can someone provide me a proof of that?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question....

Comment: -1 for stupid tags ... please think about them next time!

Comment: @tanascius: you must grade a question - not its tags. If you have problem with them - change them. Don't be too aggressive.

Comment: @kamarey: the tags belong to the question - so I judge them, too. Just entering a whole sentence as tags is not enough. That is making the tagging system worthless.

Comment: But please tell me what was wrong with the tags. In entered the terms related to the question. If u tell me, i will be aware next time

Comment: @adiya, I apologize on behalf of some StackOverflowers.  We can tend to be full of ... hubris.  Just make sure your questions are complete and clear.  And if it is homework, make sure your tags include "homework".  Don't be discouraged.

Comment: @aditya: as a general rule of thumb: use tags which have been used more than 30 times before. Think before creating new tags.

Comment: But please tell me what is meant by "homework" tag?

Comment: The questions sounds like homework ... please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The tags are space separated then treated as a set, so of the tags {"addressing", "hashing", "open", "quadratic", "probing"}, "open" and "probing" might be describe a question rather than describe what a question is about; "quadratic" is more often applied to questions about the equation or curve which the probing technique is only somewhat related to. If you really want a tag to describe open addressing, use a hyphen "open-addressing" rather than the two tags "addressing" and "open"; likewise quadratic probing. But since there are no other questions with those tags, they won't be very useful.

Comment: @aditya: you can read the official FAQ about tagging: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Comment: This is not homework. I did my Data Structures course 2 years ago. Since then I had this doubt. Its just that I am posing this question now. Actually now I have started competing in programming contests. So I am doing a thorough revision of algorithms. Now please someone answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some values for choosing a and b on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing):

> For prime M > 2, most choices of a and b will make f(k,j) distinct for j in [0,(M − 1) / 2]. Such choices include a = b = 1/2, a = b = 1, and a = 0,b = 1. Because there are only about M/2 distinct probes for a given element, it is difficult to guarantee that insertions will succeed when the load factor is > 1/2.

A proof for the guarantee of finding the empty slots is [here](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page241.html) or [here](http://condor.depaul.edu/~ntomuro/courses/417/notes/qp.html).

Comment: On wikipedia, if prime table size is 2^m , then they have given some values of a & b, but choosing prime table size as 2^m, it will depend on only last m bits which is a poor choice

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. They give the example of 2^m (in wikipedia m is n). But the next paragraph they are talking of a prime M > 2 (in wikipedia they write M as m). That is the paragraph I quoted.

Comment: I m saying that hash table size must be prime but if we 2^m then it wont be prime

Comment: Yes, it should be prime. In wikipedia they have two cases. And the second one is about prime sizes. That should be alright.

Comment: @tanascius. Thank you very much. The first link does not work though :/